# Jquery scroll dosn't work if i load new data on a div

Tags: jquery

I don't know what's the problem in my code, i did some search about this problem but i don't know how to make my code work. 
i made a simple demo of my problem on *jsfiddle*. this is the link: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mm2Lvjsw/)

this is my code:

```
$(function() {
  $('.container').scroll(function() {
   alert('scroll');
  });
   $('.clickMe').click(function () {
     $('.dddd').html('<div class="container"><div class="my_div">test</div></div>');
  })
})
```

what i want is how to make the scroll event work if some new data was loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind on the new content.  Binding only works on elements that exist at the time it executed.

```
$(function() {
    var scrollHandler = function(){
        alert('scroll');
    };

    $('.container').on('scroll', scrollHandler);

    $('.clickMe').on('click', function () {
        $('.dddd').html('<div class="container"><div class="my_div">test</div></div>');
        $('.dddd').find('.container').on('scroll', scrollHandler);
    });
});
```